# Type mismatch error : passing class public get property as argument to sub procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pass to seperate class properties who are identical in code except that they point to two different cells to a sub procedures  with two arguments.

I'm getting a type mismatch error but can't figure out why it's  happening.... can't you pass class properties to sub procedures?

Code from class

```
Public Property Get Signal() ' this code is in the EURO_USD class

Dim rowA_status As String
rowA_status = Worksheets("EURO_USD").Cells(rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Value

Select Case rowA_status
    Case Not ""
        Signal = rowA_status
        ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("State_euro_usd").Value = rowA_status
    Case ""
        Signal = "no news"

End Select

End Property

Public Property Get Signal() As String 'This code is in the DNB_EMA class NOT EURO_USD class

Dim rowA_status As String
rowA_status = Worksheets("DNB_EMA").Cells(rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)

Select Case rowA_status.Value
    Case Not ""
        Signal = rowA_status
        ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("").Value = rowA_status
    Case ""
        Signal = "no news"

End Select

End Property
```

Other code

```
Private sub run() ' start the email_handler
Dim email_handler As Object: Set email_handler = New email_handler

email_handler.Send EURO_USD.Signal, DNB_EMA.Signal <---- this generates type mismatch error!

End sub

Sub Send(Action_EURO_USD As String, Action_DNB_EMA As String) ' send news

Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application: Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With outMail
    .To = ""
    .Subject = "Bot_Trading_Status"
    .body = "Status for EURO_USD: " & Action_EURO_USD & vbCrLf & "Status for DNB_EMA: " & Action_DNB_EMA
    .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It appears you have two procedures with the same identifier: `Public Probperty Get Signal()`. Does this code even compile?  I get an "Ambiguous name detected" compile error.

Comment: Both declarations of the `Get` procedure return a `Variant`, but your email `Send` procedure requires a string.  That is certainly the cause of type mismatch error.

Comment: Does declarations of get always return variants? When I declare the property as string ( public property get Signal as string ) I still get the same error. Also when I try typename(euro_usd.signal) I get an error, how did you check the type of the property ?

Comment: No its returning variant because toy have either specified that or omitted an explicit type in the `Get` procedure. This code shouldn't even compile. Can you answer my first question?  Does this compile and if so please show the full code for the class module.

Comment: The code compiles, there are two classes. one is the EURO_USD class and the second is the DNB_EMA class. Both have a signal property ( the code are basically identical so I didn't add the other class )

Comment: You don't indicate there are two classes. Please remove the redundant code and clarify the remainder: is `email_handler` a class module or a normal module?  **Please provide the minimum code for someone else to reproduce your problem...**

Comment: When I try and guess at how you're implementing this, and step through the code, it breaks on `Signal = rowA_status`. It's impossible to help you further unless I know how you're calling these procedures.

Comment: rowA_status is the last empty row in colummn "E" on sheet EURO_USD and DNB_EMA respectively, it is clear from the code above. 
Anyway, I tracked down the error to the select case statement, switching it to an If statement makes the error go away ( all variables and properties was initially defined as string ) so that it pops up a type mismatch error is very strange.

Comment: Yes, that is what I observe, the error happens within the `Signal` method, because your case statement I think is attempting a boolean evaluatino of the string, which is a mismatch.  I am writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I create an ordinary module `"main"` and put this:

```
Sub foo()

Dim euro As myClass

'instantiate the class object
Set euro = New myClass

Call email_handler.Send(euro.Signal, "blah")

End Sub
```

Your class module code is actually breaking, it's not a mismatch in the function call to `.Send` procedure, but it's unable to evaluate the `Signal` property, and that error bubbles up to the calling procedure.

**The error arises because this line is attempting a boolean evaluation against a string data type,** which is the source of the Mismatch error.

```
Case  Not ""
```

I revise the class module named `"myClass"`, and in my example it **only** contains this code.  You can still use a `Case` statement, but change it like so:

```
Public Property Get Signal() As String

Dim rowA_status As String
rowA_status = Worksheets("EURO_USD").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Value

Select Case rowA_status
    Case vbNullString
        Signal = "no news"
    Case Else
        'equivalent to: NOT ""

        Signal = rowA_status
        ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("State_euro_usd").Value = rowA_status

End Select

Signal = rowA_status

End Property
```

Comment: Appreciated! Thank you for taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

The select case causes the error, changing it to an If statement solves the issue. However I do not know why this is the case.